# Updating A Single Attribute in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to ask how to directly update a single attribute in rails. I've already tried many ways to solve it but none of them works. Currently, in my view I have this line of code:

`<%= link_to("Ban", admin_update_path(user), :confirm => "Are you sure?")%>`

Then in my controller:

```
def update 
       @user = User.first

        if @user.update_attributes(:reputation =>1)
            redirect_to admin_viewAllUsers_path, :notice => "User banned!"
        else
            render "index"
        end  

    end
```

Then in my routes:

```
get "admin/edit"
put "admin/update"
```

Note:
If I used put "admin/update" in my routes, I would get "No route matches [GET] "/admin/update.2" error, but when I used get "admin/update" I didn't get any error but my :reputation wouldn't update. Btw, :reputation is an integer

Moreover, If I use User.find(params[:id]) instead of User.first, I'll get "Couldn't find User without an ID" error.

Pls help. What should I do? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: what exactly is your error?

Comment: currently, I don't have an error, but my user won't update. The user_attributes didn't work.

Comment: what is your :reputatation field type?

Comment: check what error is returned by `#update_attributes`. try adding a debug line before the `render 'index'` line

Comment: Look at the log file to see if you get a warning about reputation not being mass-assignable then check what you have for attr_accessible or attr_protected in your user model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For single attribute you can use:

```
@user.update_attribute(:reputation,1)
```

For my opinion update action it is smth different(change name,surname etc.) not only ban, I think you should create action `ban`:

```
    def ban 
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @user.update_attribute(:reputation,1)
      redirect_to admin_viewAllUsers_path, :notice => "User banned!"
    end
```

and routes for it:

```
match 'admin/users/:id/ban', :to => 'users#ban', :as => 'admin_user_ban', :via => :post
```

and finally link:

```
<%= link_to("Ban", admin_user_ban_path(user), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :post)%>
```

Comment: it didn't work. is it because of my routes? If I used put "admin/update" in my routes, I would get "No route matches [GET] "/admin/update.2" error, but when I used get "admin/update" I didn't get any error but my :reputation wouldn't update. Btw, :reputation is an integer

Comment: you are right, I updated my answer and you can look to @Swards answer

Answer (score 1):

why not

```
@user.reputation = 1
if @user.save
  #do something
else
  puts "Did not save"
end
```

is reputation in your accessible_attributes?

Comment: unless its an api i recomment using "POST" or add :method => :put

Comment: is it because I used User.first instead of User.find(params[:id])?

Answer (score 0):

Your route is expecting the PUT method.  Something along these lines...

```
<%= link_to("Ban", admin_path(user), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :put)%>
```

The edit and put methods that you have in your routes file don't indicate an :id attribute.  In your case, something like this:

```
get "admin/:id/edit"
put "admin/:id"
```